(Zend) PDF Form field - encoding issue with european (Czech) characters
Helo again, I hope this is my last issue with creating PDF form (upgrading old Zend PDF library I am stuck with).
At this moment, I can add a form field to the PDF, but when I try to make the filed prefilled, I run into character encoding problems. Czech language uses a lots of special characters (áéěžčš...) that I can't get right in the form field. I can display the text properly in the stream in the (...) Tj but the (default) value in the /V entry has always broken encoding.
First of all, I got certain I am using suitable font that includes these characters. (Sadly the default Helvetica and other fonts included in Zend PDF don't have these characters "defined"?) To display the value in (...) Tj, I am using Zend PDF's own $font->encodeString($value, 'UTF-8') function that works fine. Using that same function to get the value in /V entry just doesn't work. I have tried it with different encodings, without encoding the value... But just can't get it working right.
I have stumbled over a similar issue here: but can't find my way around the encoding using this either.
I have tried to create an empty form, write the value, save the PDF and check the result source code. (It only worked in Mozilla because Acrobat reader encodes the whole PDF and Chrome adds it's own fonts... Mozilla only overrides the widget by adding it to the end of the file again filled.) The value in the /V entry is almost the same as my encoded value in (...) Tj, it only has a "ţ˙" at the start I have no idea how to put there and if it is the thing that makes all the difference.

Can you amazing folk think of way how to have the Czech special characters displayed in the value of the field?
Once again, it looks that Acrobat ignores the font I set for the field (but at least when filling the field, it has a font with Czech characters) and Chrome has some troubles with characters width - or I have missed something really obvious again.

Also, I have noticed that default Zend PDF fonts don't have these special characters, even though I know for certain that both Times and Courier have them. (I thought Helvetica should have them too.) Is there a way how to upgrade the Zend PDF fonts so they include these characters?
I am uploading two PDF files, one is empty, the other has the value prefilled.
The testing string we can use is "€ Příliš žluťoučký kůň" (€ sign is just to add more characters, the rest is a usual testing string for Czech fonts.)
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/i14YBMbv#link
Here is a source code of the PDF without filled value:
(I had to remove the content of the font streams so the post fits the characters limit here)
%PDF-1.5
%âăĎÓ
1 0 obj 
<</Type /Catalog /Version /1.5 /Pages 2 0 R /Acroform <</Fields [4 0 R ] >> /Names 7 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj 
<</Type /Pages /Kids [8 0 R ] /Count 1 >>
endobj
3 0 obj 
<</Length 49 /Type /XObject /Subtype /Form /BBox [0 0 150 30 ] /Resources <</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageC /ImageB /ImageI ] /Font <</F1 10 0 R >> >> 
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0 ] >>
stream
/Tx BMC 
BT 
/F1 11 Tf 0 g
0 0 Td 
() Tj 
ET 
EMC
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj 
<</Type /Annot /Subtype /Widget /FT /Tx /Rect [200 395 350 425 ] /T (yourname) /DA (/F1 11 Tf 0 g) /Q 0 /F 4 /Ff 0 /DR <</Font <</F1 10 0 R >> >> 
/AP <</N 3 0 R >> /P 8 0 R >>
endobj
5 0 obj 
[]
endobj
6 0 obj 
<</Names 5 0 R >>
endobj
7 0 obj 
<</Dests 6 0 R >>
endobj
8 0 obj 
<</Type /Page /LastModified (D:20240405191945+02'00') /Resources <</ProcSet [/Text /PDF /ImageC /ImageB /ImageI ] /Font <</F1 10 0 R >> >> 
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842 ] /Contents [9 0 R ] /Annots [4 0 R ] /Parent 2 0 R >>
endobj
9 0 obj 
<</Length 106 >>
stream
/F1 14 Tf
0 g
BT
40 400 Td
( ¬   PY í l ia  ~ l ue o u\r k ý   koH) Tj
ET
1 g
200 395 150 30 re
 S

endstream
endobj
10 0 obj 
<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type0 /BaseFont /Montserrat-Regular /DescendantFonts [12 0 R ] /Encoding /Identity-H /ToUnicode 11 0 R >>
endobj
11 0 obj 
<</Length 361 >>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin 
12 dict begin 
begincmap 
/CIDSystemInfo 
<</Registry (Adobe) 
/Ordering (UCS) 
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def 
/CMapType 2 def 
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF> 
endcodespacerange 
1 beginbfrange 
<0000> <FFFF> <0000> 
endbfrange 
endcmap 
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop 
end end 
endstream
endobj
12 0 obj 
<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Montserrat-Regular /DW 600 /W 13 0 R /CIDSystemInfo 14 0 R /Subtype /CIDFontType2 /FontDescriptor 16 0 R 
/CIDToGIDMap 17 0 R >>
endobj
13 0 obj 
[0 [0 ] 13 [262 ] 32 [262 260 373 696 615 829 669 202 ] 40 41 329 42 [386 575 212 382 212 335 662 361 568 564 661 566 609 589 638 609 ] 
58 59 212 60 62 575 63 [567 1033 717 754 719 826 669 633 773 813 302 501 711 589 955 813 839 718 839 723 615 574 792 698 1111 656 635 651 318 335 318 576 
500 ] 
97 [590 678 563 678 604 339 686 677 269 274 601 269 1061 677 627 ] 112 113 678 114 [401 489 406 673 542 879 534 542 511 334 295 334 575 ] 
160 [262 260 563 637 700 695 295 490 ] 169 [809 401 477 575 382 809 ] 176 [419 575 ] 178 179 430 181 [678 632 252 ] 185 [430 414 477 ] 
188 190 1029 191 [567 ] 192 197 717 198 [1033 719 ] 200 203 669 204 207 302 208 [831 813 ] 210 214 839 215 [575 839 ] 217 220 792 
221 [635 718 668 ] 224 229 590 230 [986 563 ] 232 235 604 236 239 269 240 [633 677 ] 242 246 627 247 [575 627 ] 249 252 673 253 [542 678 542 717 590 717 590 717 590 719 563 719 563 719 563 719 563 826 678 831 678 669 604 669 604 669 604 669 604 669 604 773 
686 773 686 773 686 773 686 813 677 823 677 302 269 302 269 302 269 302 269 302 269 718 543 501 274 711 601 590 589 269 589 269 589 
269 589 314 594 279 813 677 813 677 813 677 721 813 677 839 627 839 627 839 627 1121 1068 723 401 723 401 723 401 615 489 615 489 
615 489 615 489 574 406 574 406 574 416 792 673 792 673 792 673 792 673 792 673 792 673 1111 879 635 542 635 651 511 651 511 651 
511 295 ] 
399 [817 ] 402 [438 ] 416 [839 627 ] 431 [797 679 ] 439 [615 ] 452 [1456 1337 1202 1090 863 543 1315 1087 951 717 590 ] 467 [792 673 ] 
484 [806 691 773 686 711 601 839 627 ] 494 [615 514 ] 506 [717 590 1033 986 839 627 717 590 717 590 669 604 669 604 302 269 302 269 839 627 839 627 723 401 723 401 792 673 792 673 615 489 
574 406 ] 
542 [813 677 ] 554 [839 627 839 627 ] 560 [839 627 635 542 ] 567 [274 ] 601 [604 ] 658 [514 ] 697 [202 373 266 222 ] 712 [166 ] 716 
[166 ] 768 772 0 774 780 0 783 [0 ] 785 786 0 795 [0 ] 803 804 0 806 808 0 814 [0 ] 817 [0 ] 821 824 0 916 [717 ] 937 [902 ] 956 
[678 ] 960 [722 ] 1024 1025 659 1026 [825 572 707 627 309 302 527 1186 1184 835 702 824 680 806 744 727 749 572 794 659 1011 636 ] 
1048 1049 824 1050 [702 785 963 821 851 825 710 716 588 680 917 650 827 731 1094 1117 820 978 710 706 1092 732 583 659 608 475 651 618 826 534 ] 
1080 1081 688 1082 [581 632 790 675 636 674 686 563 473 558 785 526 684 599 ] 1096 1097 929 1098 [621 785 563 571 865 606 625 618 671 475 572 528 273 269 274 921 944 670 581 688 558 639 ] 
1122 [802 596 ] 1130 [884 680 ] 1138 [851 646 748 576 ] 1162 [848 708 735 593 732 697 575 449 608 502 701 592 1052 862 636 534 748 581 728 597 724 581 813 646 845 694 1088 877 ] 
1192 [972 794 716 563 588 473 652 559 652 559 690 526 967 757 755 620 731 599 731 670 974 752 974 752 310 1011 826 702 581 ] 1222 
[652 816 682 845 695 728 597 992 816 274 744 583 744 583 1026 990 659 625 824 617 824 617 1011 826 636 534 615 514 824 688 824 688 
851 636 851 646 851 646 706 571 680 558 680 558 680 558 731 599 572 475 978 785 609 478 651 524 668 555 ] 
1296 [635 534 787 632 ] 1306 [855 686 1072 928 ] 1316 [849 674 798 692 817 675 ] 1326 [809 651 ] 7688 [719 563 ] 7692 [826 678 826 678 ] 
7700 [669 604 669 604 ] 7708 [669 604 ] 7712 [773 686 ] 7716 [813 677 ] 7722 [813 677 ] 7726 [302 269 ] 7734 [589 269 ] 7738 [589 269 ] 
7746 [955 1061 813 677 813 677 813 677 813 677 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 ] 7770 [723 401 ] 7774 [723 401 615 489 615 489 615 489 615 489 615 489 ] 
7788 [574 406 574 406 ] 7800 [792 673 792 673 ] 7808 [1111 879 1111 879 1111 879 ] 7822 [635 542 ] 7826 [651 511 ] 7831 [406 ] 7838 
[756 ] 7840 [717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 669 604 669 604 669 604 669 604 
669 604 669 604 669 604 669 604 302 269 302 269 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 
631 839 627 792 673 792 673 797 679 797 679 797 679 797 679 797 679 635 542 635 542 635 542 635 542 ] 
8199 [700 212 131 100 0 ] 8208 [382 ] 8210 [700 500 ] 8212 8213 1000 8216 8218 212 8220 8222 382 8224 8225 547 8226 [295 ] 8230 [647 ] 
8240 [1190 ] 8242 [202 373 ] 8249 8250 299 8260 [169 ] 8274 [514 ] 8304 [430 ] 8308 8313 430 8320 8329 430 8353 [719 ] 8355 [654 637 ] 
8358 [870 1617 ] 8361 [1171 ] 8363 [678 802 628 674 ] 8369 [833 773 ] 8372 [825 719 ] 8376 8377 718 8378 [695 ] 8380 [919 739 ] 8383 
[817 ] 8467 [466 ] 8470 [1200 ] 8482 [1021 ] 8486 [902 ] 8490 [711 717 ] 8494 [887 ] 8531 8532 1029 8539 8542 1029 8596 [687 ] 8706 
[700 ] 8709 [575 717 ] 8719 [813 ] 8721 [651 575 ] 8725 [335 ] 8729 [272 796 ] 8734 [920 ] 8747 [385 ] 8776 [575 ] 8800 [575 ] 8804 
8805 575 9664 [601 ] 9674 [501 ] 10216 10217 320 42891 [241 240 ] 64257 [608 609 ] 65535 [587 ] ]
endobj
14 0 obj 
<</Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >>
endobj
15 0 obj 
<</Length 124062 /Length1 280388 /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
... % removed so the content fit's the post limit
endstream
endobj
16 0 obj 
<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Montserrat-Regular /Flags 4 /FontBBox [-824 -262 1586 1043 ] /ItalicAngle 0 /Ascent 968 /Descent -251 
/CapHeight 700 /StemV 0 /MissingWidth 587 /FontFile2 15 0 R >>
endobj
17 0 obj 
<</Length 2179 /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
... % removed so the content fit's the post limit
endstream
endobj
xref
0 18 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000123 00000 n 
0000000181 00000 n 
0000000439 00000 n 
0000000632 00000 n 
0000000651 00000 n 
0000000685 00000 n 
0000000719 00000 n 
0000000953 00000 n 
0000001110 00000 n 
0000001257 00000 n 
0000001670 00000 n 
0000001841 00000 n 
0000006551 00000 n 
0000006621 00000 n 
0000130775 00000 n 
0000130993 00000 n 
trailer
<</ID [<39643531303133353166353064333861> <32366638393266336636393431383763> ] /Size 18 /Root 1 0 R >>
startxref
133246
%%EOF

And here is the code for PDF with the value prefilled:
%PDF-1.5
%âăĎÓ
1 0 obj 
<</Type /Catalog /Version /1.5 /Pages 2 0 R /Acroform <</Fields [4 0 R ] >> /Names 7 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj 
<</Type /Pages /Kids [8 0 R ] /Count 1 >>
endobj
3 0 obj 
<</Length 99 /Type /XObject /Subtype /Form /BBox [0 0 150 30 ] /Resources <</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageC /ImageB /ImageI ] /Font <</F1 10 0 R >> >> 
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0 ] >>
stream
/Tx BMC 
BT 
/F1 11 Tf 0 g
0 8.2955 Td 
( ¬   PY í l ia  ~ l ue o u\r k ý   koH) Tj 
ET 
EMC
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj 
<</Type /Annot /Subtype /Widget /FT /Tx /Rect [200 395 350 425 ] /T (yourname) /DA (/F1 11 Tf 0 g) /Q 0 /F 4 /Ff 0 /V ( ¬   PY í l ia  ~ l ue o u\r k ý   koH) 
/DR <</Font <</F1 10 0 R >> >> /AP <</N 3 0 R >> /P 8 0 R >>
endobj
5 0 obj 
[]
endobj
6 0 obj 
<</Names 5 0 R >>
endobj
7 0 obj 
<</Dests 6 0 R >>
endobj
8 0 obj 
<</Type /Page /LastModified (D:20240405192046+02'00') /Resources <</ProcSet [/Text /PDF /ImageC /ImageB /ImageI ] /Font <</F1 10 0 R >> >> 
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842 ] /Contents [9 0 R ] /Annots [4 0 R ] /Parent 2 0 R >>
endobj
9 0 obj 
<</Length 106 >>
stream
/F1 14 Tf
0 g
BT
40 400 Td
( ¬   PY í l ia  ~ l ue o u\r k ý   koH) Tj
ET
1 g
200 395 150 30 re
 S

endstream
endobj
10 0 obj 
<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type0 /BaseFont /Montserrat-Regular /DescendantFonts [12 0 R ] /Encoding /Identity-H /ToUnicode 11 0 R >>
endobj
11 0 obj 
<</Length 361 >>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin 
12 dict begin 
begincmap 
/CIDSystemInfo 
<</Registry (Adobe) 
/Ordering (UCS) 
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def 
/CMapType 2 def 
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF> 
endcodespacerange 
1 beginbfrange 
<0000> <FFFF> <0000> 
endbfrange 
endcmap 
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop 
end end 
endstream
endobj
12 0 obj 
<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Montserrat-Regular /DW 600 /W 13 0 R /CIDSystemInfo 14 0 R /Subtype /CIDFontType2 /FontDescriptor 16 0 R 
/CIDToGIDMap 17 0 R >>
endobj
13 0 obj 
[0 [0 ] 13 [262 ] 32 [262 260 373 696 615 829 669 202 ] 40 41 329 42 [386 575 212 382 212 335 662 361 568 564 661 566 609 589 638 609 ] 
58 59 212 60 62 575 63 [567 1033 717 754 719 826 669 633 773 813 302 501 711 589 955 813 839 718 839 723 615 574 792 698 1111 656 635 651 318 335 318 576 
500 ] 
97 [590 678 563 678 604 339 686 677 269 274 601 269 1061 677 627 ] 112 113 678 114 [401 489 406 673 542 879 534 542 511 334 295 334 575 ] 
160 [262 260 563 637 700 695 295 490 ] 169 [809 401 477 575 382 809 ] 176 [419 575 ] 178 179 430 181 [678 632 252 ] 185 [430 414 477 ] 
188 190 1029 191 [567 ] 192 197 717 198 [1033 719 ] 200 203 669 204 207 302 208 [831 813 ] 210 214 839 215 [575 839 ] 217 220 792 
221 [635 718 668 ] 224 229 590 230 [986 563 ] 232 235 604 236 239 269 240 [633 677 ] 242 246 627 247 [575 627 ] 249 252 673 253 [542 678 542 717 590 717 590 717 590 719 563 719 563 719 563 719 563 826 678 831 678 669 604 669 604 669 604 669 604 669 604 773 
686 773 686 773 686 773 686 813 677 823 677 302 269 302 269 302 269 302 269 302 269 718 543 501 274 711 601 590 589 269 589 269 589 
269 589 314 594 279 813 677 813 677 813 677 721 813 677 839 627 839 627 839 627 1121 1068 723 401 723 401 723 401 615 489 615 489 
615 489 615 489 574 406 574 406 574 416 792 673 792 673 792 673 792 673 792 673 792 673 1111 879 635 542 635 651 511 651 511 651 
511 295 ] 
399 [817 ] 402 [438 ] 416 [839 627 ] 431 [797 679 ] 439 [615 ] 452 [1456 1337 1202 1090 863 543 1315 1087 951 717 590 ] 467 [792 673 ] 
484 [806 691 773 686 711 601 839 627 ] 494 [615 514 ] 506 [717 590 1033 986 839 627 717 590 717 590 669 604 669 604 302 269 302 269 839 627 839 627 723 401 723 401 792 673 792 673 615 489 
574 406 ] 
542 [813 677 ] 554 [839 627 839 627 ] 560 [839 627 635 542 ] 567 [274 ] 601 [604 ] 658 [514 ] 697 [202 373 266 222 ] 712 [166 ] 716 
[166 ] 768 772 0 774 780 0 783 [0 ] 785 786 0 795 [0 ] 803 804 0 806 808 0 814 [0 ] 817 [0 ] 821 824 0 916 [717 ] 937 [902 ] 956 
[678 ] 960 [722 ] 1024 1025 659 1026 [825 572 707 627 309 302 527 1186 1184 835 702 824 680 806 744 727 749 572 794 659 1011 636 ] 
1048 1049 824 1050 [702 785 963 821 851 825 710 716 588 680 917 650 827 731 1094 1117 820 978 710 706 1092 732 583 659 608 475 651 618 826 534 ] 
1080 1081 688 1082 [581 632 790 675 636 674 686 563 473 558 785 526 684 599 ] 1096 1097 929 1098 [621 785 563 571 865 606 625 618 671 475 572 528 273 269 274 921 944 670 581 688 558 639 ] 
1122 [802 596 ] 1130 [884 680 ] 1138 [851 646 748 576 ] 1162 [848 708 735 593 732 697 575 449 608 502 701 592 1052 862 636 534 748 581 728 597 724 581 813 646 845 694 1088 877 ] 
1192 [972 794 716 563 588 473 652 559 652 559 690 526 967 757 755 620 731 599 731 670 974 752 974 752 310 1011 826 702 581 ] 1222 
[652 816 682 845 695 728 597 992 816 274 744 583 744 583 1026 990 659 625 824 617 824 617 1011 826 636 534 615 514 824 688 824 688 
851 636 851 646 851 646 706 571 680 558 680 558 680 558 731 599 572 475 978 785 609 478 651 524 668 555 ] 
1296 [635 534 787 632 ] 1306 [855 686 1072 928 ] 1316 [849 674 798 692 817 675 ] 1326 [809 651 ] 7688 [719 563 ] 7692 [826 678 826 678 ] 
7700 [669 604 669 604 ] 7708 [669 604 ] 7712 [773 686 ] 7716 [813 677 ] 7722 [813 677 ] 7726 [302 269 ] 7734 [589 269 ] 7738 [589 269 ] 
7746 [955 1061 813 677 813 677 813 677 813 677 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 ] 7770 [723 401 ] 7774 [723 401 615 489 615 489 615 489 615 489 615 489 ] 
7788 [574 406 574 406 ] 7800 [792 673 792 673 ] 7808 [1111 879 1111 879 1111 879 ] 7822 [635 542 ] 7826 [651 511 ] 7831 [406 ] 7838 
[756 ] 7840 [717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 717 590 669 604 669 604 669 604 669 604 
669 604 669 604 669 604 669 604 302 269 302 269 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 627 839 
631 839 627 792 673 792 673 797 679 797 679 797 679 797 679 797 679 635 542 635 542 635 542 635 542 ] 
8199 [700 212 131 100 0 ] 8208 [382 ] 8210 [700 500 ] 8212 8213 1000 8216 8218 212 8220 8222 382 8224 8225 547 8226 [295 ] 8230 [647 ] 
8240 [1190 ] 8242 [202 373 ] 8249 8250 299 8260 [169 ] 8274 [514 ] 8304 [430 ] 8308 8313 430 8320 8329 430 8353 [719 ] 8355 [654 637 ] 
8358 [870 1617 ] 8361 [1171 ] 8363 [678 802 628 674 ] 8369 [833 773 ] 8372 [825 719 ] 8376 8377 718 8378 [695 ] 8380 [919 739 ] 8383 
[817 ] 8467 [466 ] 8470 [1200 ] 8482 [1021 ] 8486 [902 ] 8490 [711 717 ] 8494 [887 ] 8531 8532 1029 8539 8542 1029 8596 [687 ] 8706 
[700 ] 8709 [575 717 ] 8719 [813 ] 8721 [651 575 ] 8725 [335 ] 8729 [272 796 ] 8734 [920 ] 8747 [385 ] 8776 [575 ] 8800 [575 ] 8804 
8805 575 9664 [601 ] 9674 [501 ] 10216 10217 320 42891 [241 240 ] 64257 [608 609 ] 65535 [587 ] ]
endobj
14 0 obj 
<</Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >>
endobj
15 0 obj 
<</Length 124062 /Length1 280388 /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
... % removed so the content fit's the post limit
endstream
endobj
16 0 obj 
<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Montserrat-Regular /Flags 4 /FontBBox [-824 -262 1586 1043 ] /ItalicAngle 0 /Ascent 968 /Descent -251 
/CapHeight 700 /StemV 0 /MissingWidth 587 /FontFile2 15 0 R >>
endobj
17 0 obj 
<</Length 2179 /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
... % removed so the content fit's the post limit
endstream
endobj
xref
0 18 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000123 00000 n 
0000000181 00000 n 
0000000489 00000 n 
0000000733 00000 n 
0000000752 00000 n 
0000000786 00000 n 
0000000820 00000 n 
0000001054 00000 n 
0000001211 00000 n 
0000001358 00000 n 
0000001771 00000 n 
0000001942 00000 n 
0000006652 00000 n 
0000006722 00000 n 
0000130876 00000 n 
0000131094 00000 n 
trailer
<</ID [<37666636353635333732376335386435> <62373065623661313761376634383731> ] /Size 18 /Root 1 0 R >>
startxref
133347
%%EOF


@KJ I think every type of reader (Acrobat, Chrome or Mozilla) more or less break and mess up with the original PDF when you save it with filled fields. I don't mind that actually. What bothers me is that I just can't get the default value displayed in the form field. I have just tried to fill the /V with HEX (used php bin2hex()) and it still doesn't work. (By the way, when I fill and save the file in acrobat and then decompress it, the /V is not in HEX but the PDF gets "upgraded" to 1.6.)

@KJ I admit I am a bit lost... However, based on your notice, converting the value string for /V from UTF-8 to UTF-16 did the trick and I can see the form field filled "right". Of course, when the filed has a focus, Acrobat has it in it's own font (which I don't mind that much) and Chrome has issues with character widths. (See the picture in the original post with the "P" and "ří" on the same place.) It seems like the special characters are in a different font and that it can't get their width right. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

@KJ Honestly, I have no idea how would I even do the deleting the font metrics... (and if it was worth it) I know Arial, but we've stopped using it for PDF files because it is simply too big. (A 2-3 page PDF file with some text, basic graphics and Arial embeded was almost 1MB which seemed too much to our clients.) I did a bit more testing and funnily enough, it is the "€" character that has it's width calculated wrong in Chrome and moves "P" to the position of "ří".

If you don't mind, look at the code again and let's assume the font is fine as it is and I have just made some stupid mistake in setting the Annotation. I just can't see it. Can you think of some entry for the text filed widget that should be there (or should be set differently) to get the result better?

@KJ When I embed Arial that I have in my PC, the filesize climbs to about 600 kB which is something I want to avoid. How did you do it that your file is only 20 kB? I have noticed that in your source code Annot doesn't have DR entry with used fon. Neither the stream content of the field has the font defined. There is only "/Helv" in the DA of the annot but the "/Helv" is not defined anywhere. How does this even work? Does the annot inherit the fonts from the page? When I tried to do this, Acrobat seemed okay with empty field but it was not possible to have the field prefilled.

@KJ I see... I don't think I will be able to rewrite Zend so it only embeds the characters used in the text. (I think it does use only some subsets but the Arial it uses is still rather big.) Also it would not really be the solution for the form field where people can start writing Nordic names and then the needed characters will be missing. However, thank you very much for your insight and help. Now I know the (current) limits and all I have to do is to persuade our clients that they don't need the PDF forms prefilled ;-)

You have to add the BOM þÿ / 0xFE0xFF before your value in the /V entry in order to be recognized as a UTF-16 BE string and it works:
/V (þÿ ¬   PY í l ia  ~ l ue o u\r k ý   koH)

Edit: Based on our experience, the font associated with a field must be a WinAnsi encoded font (/Montserrat 9 0 R in the screenshot below) in order to be used for editing. 
For the appearance, if the field value includes characters not supported by the WinAnsi encoding, you have to create a CID font from the original editing font and subset it to include only the displayed characters (/F_43495525 13 0 R in the screenshot below).

The demo PDF file can be downloaded here: https://o2sol.com/download/so/78281526-zend-pdf-form-field-encoding-issue-with-european-czech-characters/MontserratFontForTextBox.pdf

thank you for your input, we've already figured that the string for /V entry has to be in UTF-18 BE. The ongoing issue is that Acrobat ignores font set for the field and obviously renders the prefilled value in different font and/or size. And that Chrome can't find the width of certain characters. It seems to me that the form fields/annots have their own behaviors that are set by the reader (acrobat, chrome, mozilla) and can't always be overriden.

@iPDFdev The information about WinAsci encoded font is interesting one. My understanding of fonts isn't that wast but I will try to look to it when I can get back to this. (I have to leave this project for couple days). Although I am not sure if I can bend Zend PDF library to do this. I have just noticed today, that if I fill the field in Chrome and then save the PDF, the Chrome creates some font with the subset but the special characters are actually missing. And it is not only with my PDF files but from other creators too - even with yours.
